# Does Javascript not have built in support for formatting date objects?

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

Does Javascript not have any built in support for formatting dates? I have a date object, and I want to format it to a format of my choice e.g. the date that I want to convert is '2017-12-22'. Is there not any function that I could use

something like  `var newFormattedDate = new Date('2017-12-22', 'mm/dd/yyyy')`

so that the output is 22/12/2017

Comment: First, No. JS does not have one. You can look into `localeDateString` or `DateString` functions but they have compatibility issues and are not consistent with format. Second, HOW in the world are you expecting format as `22/12/2017` when you pass format as `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have support for formatting.

Comment: @Rajesh Here's a link to how I expect to pass format as dd/mm/yy as opposed to mm/dd/yy: https://gist.github.com/mlconnor/1887156  . Thanks for the info though

Comment: @RafeyHijazy You should look into `moment.js`

Comment: Alright. Thanks Rajesh.

Comment: it doesn't and this is incredible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have support to give format to date. You can use `moment.js`.

Alternatively, you can use `string#replace`.

```js
console.log('2017-12-22'.replace(/(....)-(..)-(..)/g,'$3/$2/$1'));
```

Comment: You are restricting your date string to have only 1 separator.

Comment: Or there is `'2017-12-22'.split(/\D/).reverse().join('/')`. ;-)